# Why is DECLARE_DYNAMIC & IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC nessary for DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST?

Tags: c++, dynamic, mfc, downcast

I have two classes:

```
/*Switch.h*/
    class CSwitch : public CDeviceEntity {}
/*EndSystem.h*/
    class CEndSystem : public CDeviceEntity {}
```

but when I use:

```
CDeviceEntity* dev = NULL;
dev = topo->headList[i]->node;
if ( DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CEndSystem, dev ) != NULL ) {}
```

"`DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST`" always returns `not NULL` while dev is kind of `class CEndSystem` or `class CSwitch`.

If use:

```
/*Switch.h*/
    class CSwitch : public CDeviceEntity { DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CSwitch) } 
    and
/*Switch.cpp*/
    IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CSwitch, CDeviceEntity)
/*EndSystem.h*/
    class CEndSystem : public CDeviceEntity { DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CEndSystem) }
    and
/*EndSystem.cpp*/
    IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CEndSystem, CDeviceEntity)
```

"`DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST`" returns `NULL` or `not NULL` according to `class CEndSystem` or `class CSwitch`.

Why "`DECLARE_DYNAMIC`" and "`IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC`" are nessary for "`DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST`"?

```
/*Algorithm.h*/
static int getESNum();

/*Algorithm.cpp*/
int CAlgorithm::getESNum()
{
    int count = 0;
    CDeviceEntity* dev = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < topo->nodeNum; i++)
    {
        dev = topo->headList[i]->node;
        if ( DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CEndSystem, dev ) != NULL )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

/*Algorithm.h*/
static int getSWNum();

/*Algorithm.cpp*/
int CAlgorithm::getSWNum()
{
    int count = 0;
    CDeviceEntity* dev = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < topo->nodeNum; i++)
    {
        dev = topo->headList[i]->node;
        if ( DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CSwitch, dev) != NULL )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

And the functions are called in serialization when saving the document.

Comment: Where are the declarations of `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` etc.?

Comment: Could you at least mention where `DYNAMIC_CAST`, `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` and `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` come from? I have never encountered them.

Comment: @Rubby But you haven’t given us what I asked for, only added irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST is a throw back to how you used to have to do dynamic casting before [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) information was available from the compiler. The casting information is created using the macros DECLARE_DYNAMIC and IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC which use the class CRuntimeClass to decide if the cast is valid.

DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST simply does this:

```
CObject* AFX_CDECL AfxDynamicDownCast(CRuntimeClass* pClass, CObject* pObject)
{
    if (pObject != NULL && pObject->IsKindOf(pClass))
        return pObject;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

The DECLARE_DYNAMIC macro adds this code:

```
#define DECLARE_DYNAMIC(class_name) \
protected: \
    static CRuntimeClass* PASCAL _GetBaseClass(); \
public: \
    static const CRuntimeClass class##class_name; \
    static CRuntimeClass* PASCAL GetThisClass(); \
    virtual CRuntimeClass* GetRuntimeClass() const; \
```

Add IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC adds this code:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_RUNTIMECLASS(class_name, base_class_name, wSchema, pfnNew, class_init) \
CRuntimeClass* PASCAL class_name::_GetBaseClass() \
    { return RUNTIME_CLASS(base_class_name); } \
AFX_COMDAT const CRuntimeClass class_name::class##class_name = { \
    #class_name, sizeof(class class_name), wSchema, pfnNew, \
        &class_name::_GetBaseClass, NULL, class_init }; \
CRuntimeClass* PASCAL class_name::GetThisClass() \
    { return _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name); } \
CRuntimeClass* class_name::GetRuntimeClass() const \
    { return _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name); }

#define IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(class_name, base_class_name) \
    IMPLEMENT_RUNTIMECLASS(class_name, base_class_name, 0xFFFF, NULL, NULL)
```

I imagine few people still use this for new projects, instead preferring the C++ standard `dynamic_cast<>` call (along with `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`).